# AngularJs URL with a parameter

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Users of my app have a wristband which has an NFC tag. NFC tags can be encoded with a URL, but then I have to use the same URL for all aspects of the app.

The user presents the wristband at various devices, each of which has a different functionality.

I ***have to*** combine all of those functionalities into a single app. Much as I would like to have one app per functionality, I am forbidden to.

So, normally, I would have URLs along the lines of `http://<app URL>/functionality_X`, where the user visits `http://<app URL>/` and the logic would `$state.go("functionality_X")`.

Now, the wristbands need to be uniquely identified, so the each have a URL encoded along the lines of `http://<app URL>?tag_id=1234`.

Which results, after state change, in the browser displaying `http://<app URL>?tag_id=1234#/<functionality_X>`.

Is there some way that I can make the displayed URL less ugly?

Comment: could use a resove to capture the url values and store in a service then redirect to a more generic looking url that only resolves if the prior data exists. Not really clear how they arrive at this url in the first place

Comment: Well, I already get the `tag_id` from the URL ***before*** changing state. I also don't understand how that parameter remains part of the new URL after stae change :-(